# AWS Lambda function appends X-Amz-Signature to S3 URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to have a Go Lambda function write an image to an S3 bucket that will be accessed by a public URL by the client. When I execute the function locally, with my AWS credentials in my environment, I can access the image at the s3 url ending in /image.jpg. When the lambda function runs though, it adds an Amz-signature to the URL.

The function has the IAM role AmazonS3FullAccess.

My question is how do I either:

1. Not have the function add this signature, so the client can access the plain URL directly.
2. Obtain this signature on the client side so it can be appended to the URL there.

In my Go function, I'm uploading to s3 using the s3 upload.upload() function, but would it make any difference if I used putObject() instead?

Answer (score 1):

There are few different ways to get the files

1. You can build the url and point to the file in s3, but it required
   the public access and allow cors to the specific bucket.

   example: https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/how-allow-public-access-amazon-bucket/
2. If you need to have a your own domain, you can use AWS Cloudfront to redirect to s3 bucket URL.
3. Using getObject() to get the file and response to the client.